# Two images similar - Measurement

Tags: image-processing, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have to decide, if two images (one template image, one warped image) are almost similar. The images can have some differences in the brightness, some marks on it or different numbers. It could also be that the warped image is shifted by 1 or 2 pixels. (See my example images!)

How can I solve this? I am using OpenCV/C++.

Comment: Don't you have some control over the acquisition procedure? I mean, why is the image warped/distorted?

Comment: this step is already done! but i have to check if something went wrong..

Comment: Why did you delete the example images from your question? Please put them back in!

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure that a global measure on images will not work alone. Particularly, to find out whether the numbers are the same will not work with an image-wide measure.
My first guess would be, to make at least a three step procedure.

### 1. Find the black marks in the corner

I don't know how much background you have on image registration, but this should probably work with a very light version. Search for every black mark separately. First you smooth your image slightly (may a Gaussian with r=1) to suppress noise and then you binarize your image with a very low threshold to kill almost every "non-black" part. This looks in a good image like this

[image]

You see that those marks with nothing around were made exactly for those applications. Now, the easiest version I can imagine is maybe something like that: Take a reasonable region of each corner. *Reasonable* means, the black mark should definitely be in there. Now you calculate the *mean of all black pixel positions*. This is your guess for the center of one black mark. In the case above, this guess is perfect and should give the real center. However, if the image is of bad quality, there are maybe noise/wrong black pixels in this region.

In this case a *rigid registration* step could be required. Since you only try to find black squares, this registration should be not really hard to implement.

### 2. Finding the numbers

When you found the black corner-marks, you know that these span a rectangle and you can calculate the regions where the important numbers are. If *good* images are really only off by some pixel, then this step is maybe unnecessary and you can take fixed regions for your numbers.

For instance, see the lower right number: it is always directly between the bottom-marks, on the right side ranging from say 1/4 of the length between the bottom-marks to almost the right mark. You have to measure this region better, but given your mark-positions, you can express this region depending on the black marks.

### 3. Comparing the number-regions (character recognition)

As mentioned in the beginning, I'm not sure whether comparing two regions of numbers by an image-measure for the whole region is good enough. You can try of course and see whether it works. But I would be suspicious of whether the difference between a 1 and a 7 is so large, that you can say for sure, *those regions match* or *they don't match*.

Since you can extract the region with the number quite good, why not using some basic OCR and comparing not the image of numbers, but the numbers itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you can I would pick some fiducials ahead of time and find their locations and relative positions. Ensure there is a correct number and their layout is 'close enough'. Examples of fiducials from those examples are the 'red triangle in the upper left corner', Text headings, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If these images are representative, I suggest thresholding the red channel, and calculating histograms of the horizontal and vertical projections (averages along rows and columns, respectively).  The histograms of matching query images should be reasonably close to those of the prototype images.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a similar problem, and we used a number of affine transforms to compare the image space of a grid in the template image to the image space of a grid in the warped image. I think that once you can "unwarp" portions of the image the rest of the image processing should be more straightforward.

As halirutan noted, you have some fiducial marks already. Normalized cross-correlation should identify those dark squares readily. Those define four comparison points for the coarsest affine transform.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Once you have a coarse affine transform between the template and the warped image, you can use relatively small search areas to find the triangular fiducials in the upper left corner of each grid. The quadrilateral formed by four neighbor triangles (or four red line intersections) in the warped image can then be used to find the affine transform relating that grid space to the matching grid space in the template image.

Once you have an affine transform between each grid in the template image and each grid in the warped image, you can unwarp the pixels in the warped image and do additional processing.

1. Operate in only one color plane (e.g. red from RGB)
2. Find a local threshold (e.g. moving average) to binarize the color plane. A local or adaptive threshold technique should eliminate the varying background intensity. Given your sample image, a global threshold is probably not the best choice.
3. (Maybe) do a morph close operation to simplify shapes.
4. Use a grid to identify relative density of pixels. (This is something like a normalized cross-correlation, but breaks a region into grid squares.)
5. (OR) Use simple image texture measures like Laws Texture Measures for comparison.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_texture#Laws_Texture_Energy_Measures